# Composer create project issue

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am getting the following error while creating project

C:\MAMP\htdocs>composer create-project laravel/laravel testing 5.2

Your version of PHP, 5.4.1, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot safely perform certificate validation, we strongly suggest you upgrade.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hummm... What can it be, what can it be...

Answer (score 1):

This means that your version of PHP is too old and has known vulnerabilities. You should upgrade the PHP version to at least 5.6, but I would recommand to upgrade directly to 7.0 or 7.1. They are under active support (until dec 3rd for 7.0) and have better perfomance.

Moreover laravel 5.2 needs a PHP version >= 5.5.9. It's written in the [requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation).

[Here](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) is the supported version chart of PHP. You shouldn't use any version that is in red.

Comment: i know it but the thing is that i have installed composer again with a higher version but same result and after installing mamp server again it is resolved so thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you need update your PHP version  source : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases
so  PHP 5.5.9 + for you :)

> PHP 5.5.9+
>   Since PHP 5.4 will enter "end of life" in September and will no longer receive security updates from the PHP development team, Laravel 5.1 requires PHP 5.5.9 or greater. PHP 5.5.9 allows compatibility with the latest versions of popular PHP libraries such as Guzzle and the AWS SDK.